# IE11 error in bundle.js by invalid character

Tags: typescript, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, tsconfig

I am using typescript with awesome-typescript-loader and Webpack for compile. But in IE11 it's doesn't work. I have this bug.

> SCRIPT1014
>
> bundle.js (58458,12)

And in this row I have this. I think that the problem is in character `

> const v6 = `

And this is my configuration of tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@pages": ["./pages/*"],
      "@core": ["./core/*"],
      "@pods": ["./pods/*"],
      "@common": ["./common/*"],
      "@state": ["./state/*"]
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And this is my webpack.config.js

```
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var basePath = __dirname;

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(basePath, "src"),
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    alias: {
      // Later on we will add more aliases here
      pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/pages/"),
      core: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/core/"),
      pods: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/pods/"),
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/common/"),
      state: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/state/"),
    }
  },
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./index.tsx"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(basePath, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist", // Content base
    inline: true, // Enable watch and live reload
    host: "test",
    port: 8080,
    stats: "errors-only",
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
        options: {
          useBabel: true,
          babelCore: "@babel/core" // needed for Babel v7
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "assets/img/[name].[ext]?[hash]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    //Generate index.html in /dist => https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html", //Name of file in ./dist/
      template: "index.html", //Name of template in ./src
      hash: true
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

And by .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I don't have more ideas about this problem.

Comment: You do not need to add @ babel / polyfill in entry.
.babelrc file should look like this

{
  "presets": [
    [
     "@babel/preset-env",
     {
       "useBuiltIns": "usage",
       "corejs": 3
     }
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: Try setting the targets to specifically include ie11: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets 

Specifically, it says "Sidenote, if no targets are specified, @babel/preset-env will transform all ECMAScript 2015+ code by default.". Not sure if that includes es2015. If es2015 support is assumed, it will leave the backticks. That will break things.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the character, perhaps you are using the Chinese symbol character '`'. Try to change it to English character '''.

Answer (score -1):

IE 11 does not support template literal.
template literal is es6 syntax, so i would recommend to you use es5 target in tsconfig

if you are not sure what you can use per browsers check it [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=%60%60)

Comment: With the help of babel + core-js, you convert ES6 to ES5 and this means that also the literal template.

Comment: This example works with typescript? I use the loader of awesome-typescript-loader

Comment: Works with awesome-typescript-loader and babel + code-js
https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/tree/awesome-typescript-loader

Comment: i would let typescript compiler to do the job. since you already have to complie typescript to some javascript version, why not compli it to es5? Complie it to es6 and then let babel to transpile it to es5 is overengeneering... just my opinion